# How to spread shot gun bullets in unity 2d top down view in random directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

right now I am trying to make a shotgun to my game in unity. Right now I have a pistol, so when I point the mouse to a direction, it shoots in that direction. I want to make the shot gun similar to the pistol, but now instead of 1 bullet, I will create more bullets and each with a random spread from the direction the player wants to shoot, so that every time I shoot, each bullet will shoot in a random direction. I was thinking on changing the angle a little bit for every bullet, but I dont know exactly how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
        if (equippedWeaponPrefab.name.ToString() == "ShotGun" && playerAmmo > 0)
        {
            bulletForce = equippedWeaponPrefab.GetComponent<ShotGunScript>().bulletForce;
            playerAmmo = playerAmmo - 1;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(equippedWeaponPrefab.GetComponent<ShotGunScript>().bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
```

Right now, the bullet works like a pistol, when I click, it shoots in the same direction it is shooting and it instantiates 1 bullet per time. My biggest problem doesn't have to do with instantiating lots of bullets at the same time (I think just adding more lines with `GameObject bullet = Instantiate(equippedWeaponPrefab.GetComponent<ShotGunScript>().bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);` would do), the thing I dont know how to do is the randomness in the angle, and that is what I need help the most. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a random value to de initial rotation of the bullet before
adding the force. Try something like this:

```
//The range of the spread

Vector2 range = new Vector2(-1 , 1);


    if (equippedWeaponPrefab.name.ToString() == "ShotGun" && playerAmmo > 0)
    {
                //RandomSpread
                float bulletSpread = Random.Range(range.x, range.y);
                
                bulletForce = equippedWeaponPrefab.GetComponent<ShotGunScript>().bulletForce;
                playerAmmo -= 1;
                
                GameObject bullet = Instantiate(equippedWeaponPrefab.GetComponent<ShotGunScript>().bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation + bulletSpread/* Add randomness */);
                
                Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
     }
```